# Why can't Swift closure variable types be implicitly unwrapped optionals?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, uialertview

For example,

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:{ (x:UIAlertAction) in
...
```

will give a "Cannot find initializer with..." error.

But if I say `UIAlertAction!` or `UIAlertAction?` instead of just `UIAlertAction`, it works. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The types of these variables are all declared already in the Cocoa API. You must match them. A thing and an Optional wrapping that thing are not a match; they are two completely different types.

On the other hand, when types are known you can just omit them. So the easiest thing is for you to change `x:UIAlertAction` to simple `x` or even `_`.

Comment: Thanks! So just to clarify: when the handler is called from the Cocoa API, it's called with a parameter of `UIAlertAction!` and not `UIAlertAction`? Because sometimes I'll write closures and can just write `(x:String)` and not the explicitly unwrapped `(x:String!)`

Comment: It has only to do with what Swift knows about the Cocoa API. In Xcode 7 the API is different and your bare UIAlertAction will work.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Just out of curiosity, what changed with Xcode 7 to make this different?

Comment: The API. As I said. Apple is constantly tweaking it to make Swift's view of it better. In Xcode 7 it is not perfect but it is vastly better. You should upgrade!

Comment: Just did! Thanks for the help, Matt!